# Empty() function might not be working with Constants in PHP

Tags: php

I've been looking at it for a while and cannot figure out what the problem might be:

My Code:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    require "includes/config.php";
    require "includes/database.php";
    require "twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php";

    if(empty(CONSUMER_KEY) && empty(CONSUMER_SECRET))
    {
        exit("Please define Consumer Key and Consumer Secret Keys");
    }

    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET);
    $request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK);

    // Temporary credentials to make requests to Twitter
    $_SESSION["oauth_token"] = $request_token["oauth_token"];
    $_SESSION["oauth_token_secret"] = $request_token["oauth_token_secret"];

    switch ($connection->http_code)
    {
        case 200:
            $url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($request_token);
            header("Location:".$url);
            break;
        default:
            die("Connection to Twitter failed. Please try again."); 
    }

?>
```

And the error is:

```
 ## 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in /home/.../connect.php on line 9
 ##
```

The line 9 part starts from

```
if(empty(CONSUMER_KEY) && empty(CONSUMER_SECRET))
{
    exit("Please define Consumer Key and Consumer Secret Keys");
}
```

CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET, they are constants and defined in "includes/config.php" like below:

```
$config = parse_ini_file("config.ini");
define("CONSUMER_KEY",$config["TwitterAPI"]["Consumer_Key"]);
define("CONSUMER_SECRET",$config["TwitterAPI"]["Consumer_Secret"]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [defined](http://php.net/defined) instead of `empty` to check if a constant exists. `empty` and `isset` functions check if variables exist. If you're wanting to check if it's empty then just check the length.

Very random that this exact error happened to me about 2 hours ago...

Comment: We know it's defined, the question is if it's empty. That's why you need to cast to a boolean, as in my answer.

Comment: That's the answer: `empty` and `isset` functions check if variables exist

Comment: @Braveyard What if CONSUMER_KEY is an empty string? `defined` will still return true.

Comment: @Skilldrick right, need to check if it `== ""` or check the length of it. Casting to boolean works as long as neither are zero.

Answer (score 1):

`empty()` and `isset()` are both *language constructs*.  They are **not** functions.  The basic difference is that with a normal function, the value is passed as a parameter to the function.  So it doesn't matter what you put in the call, it's the final evaluated response that's sent to the function.  But with a language construct, it operates on what's inside the braces directly.  There's no "passing", as there's nothing to pass to.

So, `empty()` and `isset()` are made for inspecting *variables* only.  Otherwise it can't really inspect the variable since there is no variable to inspect.  A limitation, sure.  But a fairly easy one to workaround.

Now, in your case, you're trying to do `if (empty(CONSTANT))`.  That won't work.  But let's look at how we could do that:

`empty()` is basically a wrapper for `isset($foo) && $foo`.  Now, `isset()` is a wrapper for `!is_defined($foo) && !is_null($foo)` (where is_defined is a function I just made up).  So if we wanted `empty` like behavior with non-variables, all we'd need to do is:

```
if (CONSTANT) {
```

**HOWEVER**

I'd strongly revisit what you're trying to do.  With the exception of debugging switches, you should not be using constants in a way where they could have more than one value ever.  If they can have more than one value (configuration setting, etc), then they are not constants but are global variables disguised as constants.  Personally, I'd refactor the use of those constants out to configuration variables that are injected or managed better than globals.

So what do I use constants for?  For things that are truely constant.  `define('DOZEN', 12)`, `define('BITS_PER_BYTE', 8)`, `define('DAYS_PER_WEEK', 7)`.  But I try to avoid at all costs constants which may be adjusted later on.  For those uses, I would use a variable instead, as it's more semantically correct and is easier to work with for that context.

Answer (score 0):

empty() is a tricky function. 
Basically empty can be used only for variables.
You should instead use

if(defined('CONSUMER_KEY') && (constant('CONSUMER_KEY'))){

}

Comment: `is_defined()` also checks for whether it is empty or not besides being defined?

Comment: `is_defined()` isn't a valid function.  It's `defined()`...which just returns whether it is a constant that exists, not whether it's empty or not.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, the function name is defined() and it does not check if the constant is empty or not, only that it is defined. A constant can be defined to have a value of false - which will still be defined by empty. That's why you also need to check the value.

Answer (score 0):

maybe `if(!isset(CONSUMER_KEY) && !isset(CONSUMER_SECRET))`? "PAAMAYIM NEKUDOTAYIM" in hebrew  means double colon (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM).

Comment: Again...`isset` cannot be used to check if a constant exists...it is for variables.

Answer (score -1):

It [looks like](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php#98087) you'll need to cast the constant to a boolean:

```
if (((boolean) CONSUMER_KEY) && ((boolean) CONSUMER_SECRET))
```